# Meaning of "$\Leftrightarrow$"

Tags: logic, notation

I just read (at the beginning of [this Wikipedia site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)) that "$A \Leftrightarrow B$" means "A can be replaced in a logical proof with B". Is this interpretation of the symbol true?

(I have so far understood the symbol for equivalence ($\Leftrightarrow$) to mean that, given $A \Leftrightarrow B$, then if A is true then B is true and vice versa and, if A is false then B is false and vice versa.)

Comment: That is a true statement about $\Leftrightarrow$ but it is not how it is defined. So, you can regard it as a theorem about $\Leftrightarrow$ (and about proofs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\Leftrightarrow$ symbol usually means [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) :

> In logic, two statements $p$ and $q$ are *logically equivalent* if they have the same "logical content". That is, if they have the same truth value in every model.

But it can also mean [Logical biconditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) :

> the logical connective of two statements asserting "$p \text { if and only if } q$".

The two are different but strongly related concepts :

> Formulas $p$ and $q$ are *logically equivalent* if and only if the statement $p \text { iff } q$ is a [*tautology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)).

---

The link with logical proof is through the so-called *Substitution Theorem of logical equivalents* of classical propositional logic : if two formulas are logically equivalent then they are substitutable.

That is, if we have $A \Leftrightarrow B$, $C_A$ is a formula containing formula $A$ and $C_B$ is obtained replacing $A$ with $B$ in $C_A$, we have that if $C_A$ is provable also $C_B$ is.

See:

- Stephen Cole Kleene, [Mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=q-YEuuZ_j8EC&pg=PA122) (1967): **Replacement Theorem**, page 122;
- Joseph Shoenfield, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books/about/Mathematical_logic.html?id=a9zuAAAAMAAJ) (1967), **Equivalence Theorem**, page 34.

Answer (score 1):

That is essentially correct, but that is not how $A \Leftrightarrow B$ is introduced into discussion.  To be brief something like what you said is usually true as a theorem, not as a definition or axiom (See link below).

Quite commonly $A \Leftrightarrow B$ is defined after the fact to be equivalent $(A \Rightarrow B) \wedge (B \Rightarrow A)$ where $C \Rightarrow D$ is read "$C$ implies $D$".  The precise details here depend on the context and which logical system you are working with.  Given a particular context you can then state and prove various theorems that allow for substitutions.

I need to tighten up my terminology here, but hopefully you get the idea.  Please see the following link for a short precise statement of an equivalence theorem:

[Stanford: Introduction to logic --- Equivalence Theorem](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/glossary/equivalence_theorem.html)

Answer (score 0):

$$\iff \text { means *if and only if* }$$ 
Essentially we have that:

$$A\iff B \to (A \implies B) \text { AND } (B\implies A)$$

"A if and only if B is the same as A if B and B if A"